# Setting a custom user defined formatter in logger.properties file

Tags: java, logging, formatter, properties-file

I have been asked to format logger messages so that they display on a single line. The problem is that the logger has programatically defined handlers and I cannot change any of these. Is it possible to override the format of the log messages in the .properties file even though the syntax has been defined in the logger class within a logp method? I apologise for not being able to provide code. I have tried creating a custom formatter and pointing to this in the logger.properties file but the changes are not visible.

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

> I have been asked to format logger messages so that they display on a single line.

If they are all using the [SimpleFormatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/SimpleFormatter.html) then read the [example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/SimpleFormatter.html#format-java.util.logging.LogRecord-) in the API docs and configure it through the system properties or logging.properties as described in the SimpleFormatter class level documentation.

> Is it possible to override the format of the log messages in the .properties file even though the syntax has been defined in the logger class within a logp method?

The only formatting that the logger is doing is order of the parameterized message format arguments.  If you want to change that formatting you should use [localization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/logging/overview.html#a1.17) and parameterized logging.  Then you can swap out different formats by providing a different [resource bundles](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) (per build)  which allow you to change the format for each type of message key.  However, that is only formatting the LogRecord message and params.  The rest is controlled in the formatters.

> I have tried creating a custom formatter and pointing to this in the logger.properties file but the changes are not visible.

The logging.properties is executed before the programatically defined handlers are setup.  Call [LogManager.readConfiguration](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html#readConfiguration--) or after that code runs.  Keep in mind that will undo programatically defined handlers that are being setup.  However, that may not help you because if you are able to write code to trigger a re-configuration you could just write code to install your formatter on the programatically defined handlers.

Comment: Do you mean call getRegisteredHandlers and then add my custom formatter to each of them?

Comment: for each Handler in Logger.getLogger("some.logger.name").getHandlers().  handler.setFormatter(new CustomFormatter()).